# Facebook app request from Canvas App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

How i can send request to Facebook user with same text at some date:

"Last your visit in game was at 1 week ago, please check your game state"

This means, send app request from Canvas app to another FB user after 3 days or 1 week. Is it possible?

Comment: For anything you want to do “at some date”/periodically -> look into Cronjobs.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, this is first solution. More options are there?